# How to down load modis burned area extraction product

Tags: modis

How to down load modis burned area extraction product . I found a link show the product but not found where can download the product geotiff image http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov//gallery/individual.php?db_date=2015-07-30

Answer (score 1):

The page you link to is only the gallery which contains nice looking jpg's.

From the data products page, you get to http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dataprod/mod45.php which tells you that [MCD45A1](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mcd45a1) is the code to look for. In the data pool, this can be found in http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD45A1.005/ and http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD45A1.051/